# Search a combination of columns

Tags: sql, string, oracle, search, combinations

```
1   2
X   YO
X   ZE
X   FG
X   XA
A   TZ
A   YZ
A   DH
T   EN
T   ZA
T   XN
```

I need to exclude rows of combination XY,XZ,AZ,AY,TZ,TX from a table where 1 and 2 are column names.

I've used single characters to make the question easy here but they're actually proper strings.

How do I achieve this ?

I've thought of instr and Oracle Text Search but couldn't get a optimal solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE  `2`  NOT IN ('XY','XZ','AZ','AY','TZ','TX')
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4af06/2)

Comment: Thanks echo_Me. but the XY,AZ,.... are a combination of both columns "1" and "2". so that solution did not give the expected output.

Comment: i dont understand what your wished result , or how you want to filter. can you explain more and give me your wished result ?